# Interface Comparable en Java Error

Tags: java, interface

Tengo un problema con el entendimiento de la interface `Comparable`.

La aplicación por consola consiste en imprimir los respectivos objetos y comparar cual es el producto mas caro y mas barato.
El problema es que no entiendo como aplicarlo a mi aplicación para que imprima por el metodo `toString()`:

- Producto más caro:
- Producto más barato:

Este es el código funcional de la aplicacion:

Producto:

```
package ar.com.minisuper.sistema;

public abstract class Producto implements Comparable<Producto> {
    protected String nombre;
    protected int precio;

    public Producto(String nombre,  int precio) {
        this.nombre  = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;   
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Producto o) {
        return this.getPrecio()>o.getPrecio()?1:this.getPrecio()<o.getPrecio()?-1:0;
    }
}
```

Bebida:

```
package ar.com.minisuper.sistema;

public class Bebida extends Producto {
    private double unidadVenta;

    public Bebida(String nombre, double unidadVenta, int precio) {
        super(nombre, precio);
        this.unidadVenta = unidadVenta;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + " /// " + "Litros: " + this.unidadVenta + " /// " + "Precio: $" + this.precio;
    }
}
```

Shampoo:

```
package ar.com.minisuper.sistema;

public class Shampoo extends Producto {
    private int unidadVenta;

    public Shampoo( String nombre, int unidadVenta, int precio ) {
        super(nombre, precio);
        this.unidadVenta = unidadVenta;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + " /// " + "Contenido: " + this.unidadVenta + "ml" + " /// " + "Precio: $" + this.precio;
    }
}
```

Fruta:

```
package ar.com.minisuper.sistema;

public class Fruta extends Producto {
    private String unidadVenta;

    public Fruta(String nombre, int precio, String unidadVenta) {
        super(nombre, precio);
        this.unidadVenta = unidadVenta;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + " /// " + "Precio: $" + this.precio + " /// " + "Unidad de venta: " + this.unidadVenta;
    }
}
```

Y el main:

```
package ar.com.minisuper.sistema;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bebida colaZero = new Bebida( "Coca-Cola Zero", 1.5, 20 );
        Bebida cola = new Bebida( "Coca-Cola", 1.5, 18 );
        Shampoo shampoo = new Shampoo ( "Shampoo Sedal", 500, 19 );
        Fruta frutilla = new Fruta( "Frutillas ", 64, "kilo" );
        System.out.println(colaZero);
        System.out.println(cola);
        System.out.println(shampoo);
        System.out.println(frutilla);
     }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde estás teniendo el error? ¿Dónde comparas los objetos?

Comment: El error lo tengo yo en si mas que el programa, nose como implementar el metodo, no entiendo la logica de si implementandolo en productos me va a hacer la comparacion de los objetos que llame en el mentodo main para saber cual es el mayor  y menor en precio. Me tiene liado jajaja

Comment: Para saber cual de dos objetos es mayor, debes utilizar el método `compareTo()` que has implementado. Por ejemplo: obj1.compareTo(obj2). Si el resultado es mayor que 0 indica que obj1 es mayor que obj2, si el resultado es menor que 0 indica que obj1 es menor que obj2, y sino es que son iguales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La firma del metodo `compareTo` de la interfaz `Comparable` establece que debe retornar:

> un numero negativo, cero, o un numero positivo si este objeto es menor
>   que, igual que, o mayor que el objeto especificado.

Por lo que tu implementacion en `Producto`:

```
public int compareTo(Producto o) {
    return this.getPrecio() > o.getPrecio() ?
        1 : this.getPrecio() < o.getPrecio() ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Cumple con la definicion.

Ahora bien, para aprovechar esta interfaz para resolver el problema del mayor y menor precio de `Producto`, podrias utilizar los metodos de la clase `Collections`:

- `Collections.max(Collection col)`:

> retorna el maximo elemento de la coleccion especificada de acuerdo al
>   orden natural de sus elementos.

- `Collections.min(Collection col)`:

> retorna el minimo elemento de la coleccion especificada de acuerdo al
>   orden natural de sus elementos.

---

Dado lo anterior, puedes crear una coleccion con tus objetos `Producto` y luego consultar por su maximo y minimo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bebida colaZero = new Bebida( "Coca-Cola Zero", 1.5, 20 );
    Bebida cola = new Bebida( "Coca-Cola", 1.5, 18 );
    Shampoo shampoo = new Shampoo ( "Shampoo Sedal", 500, 19 );
    Fruta frutilla = new Fruta( "Frutillas ", 64, "kilo" );
    List<Producto> list = Arrays.asList(colaZero, cola, shampoo, frutilla);

    System.out.println("Producto con mayor precio: " + Collections.max(list));
    System.out.println("Producto con menor precio: " + Collections.min(list));
}
```